# I can't unwrap a model, it says "make single user"

Tags: uv

I was watching a tutorial which told me that hitting "U" would let me unwrap my model, but it opens a menu called "make single user" which doesn't do anything.

Trying to search for smart UV project manually does not unwrap my model.

Comment: you can only unwrap in edit mode, hit <tab> then make sure everything is selected then hit "U"

Comment: Thanks, it works now. What does make single user do?

Comment: If you have a bunch of copies of an object but  you want to make one of those "unique" so is completely separate from the others. You can read up how Blender handles info with Data Blocks. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/data_blocks.html